# Xamarin Forms - Multiple ZXing windows being created

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I have a function in a Xamarin Forms page named `QRPage.xaml.cs` that opens up a QR code reader using ZXing

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
            scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
                // Stop scanning
                scanPage.IsScanning = false;

                // Pop the page and show the result
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Navigation.PopAsync();
                    DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                });
            };


            // Navigate to our scanner page
            await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);           
        }
```

In my App.xaml.cs I also have my Mainpage directed at the `QRPage.xaml.cs` with the above function

`MainPage = new NavigationPage(new QRPage());`

It seems that this `var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage()` or `await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage)` is being called multiple times, as when I close it, a new one pops up, and when the app loads initially, it crashes unless I minimise and maximise the application.

What am I doing wrong? Is OnAppearing() the wrong function to use for a `once-off` page creation?

Comment: In which page OnAppering() you have declared this code?

Comment: This is in `QRPage.xaml.cs` which is directed to be the Main Page using  `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new QRPage());` in `App.xaml.cs`

Comment: Yes when you're navigating back to the QRPage again onAppearing will be called so it would be better to maintain some state so that Creation of scanner page and Navigation won't occur when Navigation.PopAsync() happens

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private bool alreadyScanned;
            protected override async void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                if(alreadyScanned)
                    return;
                var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
            scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
                // Stop scanning
                scanPage.IsScanning = false;

                // Pop the page and show the result
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Navigation.PopAsync();
                alreadyScanned = true;
                    DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                });
            };
                await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            }
```

This is a rough example it can be done in many good ways.